# Measuring 150kHz, ~30V peak waveform with good resolution

Tags: h-bridge, voltage-measurement, waveform, test, test-equipment

I am trying to choose test equipment for a systems test application and I am running into a road block with one of the specs I need to meet.

The device features an H-bridge output similar to the circuit shown below, but instead of a motor we will use some sort of load power resistor (20 ohm, I believe). VBUS in our application is ~30V and the FETs are driven such that the output seen across the load is something close to a **+/-30V peak, 150kHz waveform** (approximately a square wave)

I am just interested in measuring the peak voltage of the waveform, but with relatively good accuracy. I need resolution down to about 1mV, ideally (I believe this would be 15 or 16-bit).

What sort of test equipment would be best suited to handle this measurement?

An oscilloscope seems to typically have poor resolution at its higher volts/div ranges (5V or 10V divisions in this case, likely), but would probably be preferable if affordable enough. A digitizer can have lower bandwidth and lower sample rate, but would seem to get me the resolution I need (PXI-4080 was one option I looked at, but the 0.1dB bandwidth is only 20kHz).

[image: H-Bridge Example]

Comment: Good question. Presumably you need the peak voltage on a cycle-by-cycle basis, so peak-detect circuits wouldn't be acceptable?

Comment: How much will the peak vary? Could you use an oscilloscope with the range set to the +/- deviation then the 30v offset subtracted?

Comment: Those MOSFETs on the right hand side are going to melt.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shed some light on why you're trying to make this measurement and what you're hoping to get out of it.  Ideally, the load will either have +VBUS or -VBUS across it, depending how and when you take the measurement.  In reality, there will be voltage drops across the MOSFETs, and potential ringing or oscillations due to parasitic inductance in traces and wires.

Comment: @0xDBFB7 I may have overlooked the option of setting the oscilloscope to a smaller range and making the measurement just on the peak. I think that could work for my purposes. 

A peak detector would be a little too simple for what I'd like to implement. A scope would give me the option to handle more scenarios if specs change on me for some reason. I didn't mention that though, so still a good response. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Andyaka They will never be turned on at the same time. You typically use some sort of half-bridge driver in these circuits: [DGD2184](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/DGD2184.pdf)

Comment: Use the oscilloscope. Zoom in. Then move the waveform down so it fits on the screen...

Comment: @BEE I think the measurement will be used to verify that we aren't seeing more of a drop across the MOSFETs than expected. Basically I have some limits (say 27.65V < VAC < 31.23V) that the device needs to meet in order to be considered a good unit. You are right though, there will be ringing, so I'd like to be able to capture  a couple periods of the entire waveform, so I will have the ability to flag any other issues.

Comment: I believe that @Andyaka was commenting on the right hand side FETs are connected such that the body diodes will always be forward biased.  They need to be flipped to match the left side.

Comment: @BEE Ahh good point haha. This was a quick google image search pull. Not the actual circuit, just trying to give a visual. 
Thanks.

Comment: Firstly you should do some simple math; 30V = 30,000mV, 1mV/30,000mV = ~33 PPM, but resolution of 1mV traditionally means error of <+-0.5mV, so then it is +-~16PPM. If you really want to measure the absolute output voltage and use this to measure the voltage drop across the FETs with a resolution (and accuracy) of 1mV then you need something with an accuracy of +-16PPM, forget about it. You need to find some other method of doing the measurement if you really want 1mV resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I used an AM685 comparator, decades ago, to implement a tracking ADC to measure the pulse-flatness of a 120 MHz data stream needed for FM modulation of a transmitter.

The AM685 has a LATCH_ENABLE pin, thus you can control **when** the decision is made.

Decades later, National Semiconductor was using this same approach for pulse characterization in their production lines.

The AM685 has about 6 nanoseconds tpd, used only NPN transistors, and Zener diodes for level shifting between stages; the latch-dispersion-time is about 400 pico_seconds, thus you can perform a "track" at points within 1 nanosecond of sharp edge, with confidence.